# Is there a way to split into 2 inputs the Date Picker Range of Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I tried various way of transalting this code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

into something like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
  <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
  <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

The objective is to:

- use 2 datepicker input (like in the second code example)
- use one mat-date-range-picker that will open by selecting one of the two datepicker.

I noticed that you must have only one datepicker linked to a unique input (1:1).
The reason of this is that I want to have a split inputbox that I can customize graphically.

Comment: use separate template variables i.e. `[for]="picker1"`, `#picker1` and `[for]="picker2"`, `#picker2`

Comment: @AndrewAllen in this case you won't be able to use the mat-date-range-picker to select both from and to dates. It's important From a UX prospective .

Comment: Then I'm lost. What does splitting the input into two mean? Please update question to clarify

Comment: Material Angular offers a solution where the Date Range Input is a single graphical box. I want instead customize it to have 2 boxes that i can customize like 2 different entities.

Comment: So why use a range-picker rather than mat-date-picker for the second example?

Comment: because I want to use the graphics of range-picker. Range-pickers shows you a timespan in the same calendar and that's useful for the user that have to select a from-to date.